# how to execute aws apigateway post method form client?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-post, aws-api-gateway

I have created a API gateway which have both get and post method , and both have same parameters and will execute the same lambda function . my get method url is;
`https://zfd17ebjag.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/stage/cons?name=testname`

and my post method url is;

```
https://zfd17ebjag.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/stage2/cons?name=testname
```

when I call a get url it executes successfully..

but when I call a post url it show the following wrror..

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

is it any other way to call post method ?

Answer (score 0):

The way of invoking a GET and POST urls is different. GET is used to request data from a specified resource. While POST is used to send data to a server to create/update a resource.

In your case, it looks like you have enabled API Key required in Method request.

[image]

[image]

Now either you turn off API Key required or you have to send API Key in Header when calling POST Method url.
Assuming XXXXXXXXX is the API Key and Content Type is application/json. You can invoke POST url using curl. See below command.

```
curl -X POST -H "x-api-key: XXXXXXXXX" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"testname"}' https://zfd17ebjag.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/stage2/cons
```

You can also call the POST url through postman.
See screenshots.
[image]
Set post body.
[image]